# How does twos complement work for bytes in the data chunk of the AIFF format?

Tags: c++, audio, twos-complement, aiff, riff

I know the data chunk is supposed to hold the audio samples. It says in the spec that they are in twos complement but i cant work out how that works in the context. Does anyone know how this works for AIFF files?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the difficulty is? Two's complement is a method of representing signed integers and works the same everywhere.

Comment: So will a signed int variable in c++ always use twos complement to represent negative values?